# Hibernate Dialect for snowflake

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a Hibernate dialect for Snowflake? I have seen some guides used SQLServerDialect ([Refere this](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/snowflake-jdbc-hibernate.rst)). Is it safe to use SQLServerDialect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I search it on the internet and couldn't find a Dialect for that. Therefore the JdbcTemplate is used to access data as follows.

1. Added snowflake-jdbc driver maven dependency to the project.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>net.snowflake</groupId>
       <artifactId>snowflake-jdbc</artifactId>
       <version>${snowflake.jdbc.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Created Entity classes as usual
3. Then JDBCTemplate to execute the SQL and prepare the results

   ```
   @Autowired
   private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

   public List<AgeEntity> getByFilter(String test) {
     StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
     sql.append("SELECT AGE, COUNT \n");
     sql.append("FROM Sample\n");
     sql.append("WHERE a = "+test);

    return jdbcTemplate.query(
           sql.toString(),
           (rs, rowNum) ->
                   new AgeEntity(
                           rs.getString("AGE"),
                           rs.getLong("COUNT")
                   )
     );
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the SQLServer2012Dialect. I had to make a few changes to support sequences and correct the datetime type. My usage is limited so other corrections may be necessary, but the code below seems to work for standard selects & inserts, limits, create DDL, and sequences (and perhaps more).

```
import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.MappingException;
import org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect;

public class SnowflakeDialect extends SQLServer2012Dialect {

    
    public SnowflakeDialect() {
        super();
        registerColumnType( Types.TIMESTAMP, "datetime" );
    }


    @Override
    public String getSequenceNextValString(String sequenceName) {
        return "select " + getSelectSequenceNextValString( sequenceName ) + " from dual";
    }

    @Override
    public String getSelectSequenceNextValString(String sequenceName) {
        return sequenceName + ".nextval";
        
    }
    

    public String getCreateSequenceString(String sequenceName, int initialValue, int incrementSize) throws MappingException {
        return getCreateSequenceString( sequenceName ) + " start " + initialValue + " increment " + incrementSize;
    }
    


}
```